# R ggplot - Different y-axis for each panel when using "stat_compare_mean"

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet, facet-grid

Code to produce the toy data set that illustrates the problem.

```
# Load libraries
library(ggpubr)
library(datasets)
library(reshape2)

# Import dataset
data(ToothGrowth)

# Melt dataset 1 
ToothGrowth.melted <- melt(ToothGrowth, id.vars=c("supp", "dose"))

# Create second dataset with different value range, and change "len" to "lon"
ToothGrowth.melted2 <- ToothGrowth.melted %>% 
  mutate(value = value * 10)
levels(ToothGrowth.melted2$variable) <- "long"

# Concatenate the 2 datasets
new <- rbind(ToothGrowth.melted, ToothGrowth.melted2)

# Create plot 
compare_list <- list(c("0.5", "1"), c("0.5", "2"), c("1", "2"))
ggbarplot(new, x = "dose", y = "value", 
          add = "mean_se", 
          facet.by = c("variable", "supp"),
          scales = "free",
          fill = "supp", 
          color = "black",
          palette = c("grey", "grey")) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  labs(x="\nDose", y="Value\n") + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons=compare_list) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 60)
```

This outputs the following figure:
[image]

How can I define where the paired comparison p-values (to reduce space between horizontal comparison bars and barplots) and the main p-value from the Kruskal-Wallis test appear in each facet? I have tried `+ stat_compare_means(label.y = c("60","60","500","500"))` but this does not work.

Comment: You should add labels in normalized parent coordinates, try `+ stat_compare_means(label.y.npc = 0.8)` or `+ stat_compare_means(label.y.npc = "middle")`

Comment: Thank you @atsyplenkov. This worked perfectly fine for the Kruskal-Wallis p-value. Is it possible to do the same for the paired comparison p-values? I'd like to reduce the white spaces between the vertical grey bars and the p-values.

Comment: I cannot figure out, how we can do it with `ggpubr`. You can rise an issue at `ggpubr`'s github. I can only suggest you to use several plots instead of facets. And the arrange them via `ggarrange`